# Advanced if/then/loop function to create new columns

Tags: r, loops

I am learning R (focused on the **tidyverse** packages) and am hoping that someone could help with the following problem that has me stumped.

I have a data-set that looks similar to the following:

```
library("tibble")
myData <- frame_data(
  ~id, ~r1, ~r2, ~r3, ~r4, ~r5, ~r6, ~r7, ~r8, ~r9, ~r10, ~r11, ~r12, ~r13, ~r14, ~r15, ~r16,
  "A", 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
  "B", 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  "C", 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
  "D", 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
  "E", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
)
```

Basically, I have multiple rows of respondent data, and each respondent gave 16 responses of either "1" or "2".

For each respondent (i.e., each row) I would like to create an additional three columns:

The first new column - called "switchCount" - identifies the number of times the respondent switched from a "2" response to a "1" response.

The second new column - called "switch1" - identifies the index of the *first* time the respondent switched from a "2" response to a "1" response.

The third new column - called "switch2" - identifies the index of the *final* time the respondent switched from a "2" response to a "1" response.

If there is no switch and all values are "2", then return the index of 0.

If there is no switch and all values are "1", then return the index of 16.

The final datatable should therefore look like this:

```
myData <- frame_data(
  ~id, ~r1, ~r2, ~r3, ~r4, ~r5, ~r6, ~r7, ~r8, ~r9, ~r10, ~r11, ~r12, ~r13, ~r14, ~r15, ~r16, ~switchCount, ~switch1, ~switch2,
  "A", 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1,
  "B", 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4,
  "C", 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 9,
  "D", 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 6, 15,
  "E", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 16, 16
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to concatenate all response columns row wise and then find the occurrences of 2,1 using `gregexpr`

```r
library(dplyr)

myData %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(concat_cols = paste(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,sep=";"),
         switchCount = ifelse(gregexpr("2;1", concat_cols)[[1]][1] == -1, 
                              0, 
                              length(gregexpr("2;1", concat_cols)[[1]])),
         switch1     = ifelse(switchCount == 0, 
                              ifelse(grepl("2",concat_cols), 1, 16),
                              min(floor(gregexpr("2;1", concat_cols)[[1]]/2)+1)),
         switch2     = ifelse(switchCount == 0, 
                              ifelse(grepl("2",concat_cols), 1, 16),
                              max(floor(gregexpr("2;1", concat_cols)[[1]]/2)+1)))  %>%
  select(-concat_cols)
```

**Output is:**

```
  id r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 r10 r11 r12 r13 r14 r15 r16 switchCount switch1 switch2
1  A  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2           0       1       1
2  B  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1           1       4       4
3  C  2  2  2  1  1  1  2  2  2   1   1   1   1   2   2   2           2       3       9
4  D  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  2   2   1   1   1   2   2   1           3       6      15
5  E  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1           0      16      16
```

**Sample data:**

```
myData <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), r1 = c(2, 2, 
2, 1, 1), r2 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1), r3 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1), r4 = c(2, 
2, 1, 2, 1), r5 = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1), r6 = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1), r7 = c(2, 
1, 2, 1, 1), r8 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1), r9 = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 1), r10 = c(2, 
1, 1, 2, 1), r11 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1), r12 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    r13 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1), r14 = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 1), r15 = c(2, 
    1, 2, 2, 1), r16 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1), switchCount = c(0, 1, 
    2, 3, 0), switch1 = c(1, 4, 3, 6, 16), switch2 = c(1, 4, 
    9, 15, 16)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```